# searching database with mongoose api and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im using nodejs and mongoose to build an api, im trying to do the search feature, but it deosnt seem to query anything, the code.

```
app.get('/search', function(req,res){
    return Questions.find({text: "noodles"}, function(err,q){
        return res.send(q);

    });
});
```

its not giving me any results, i know thier should be at least 4 results from this query, thiers 4 documents in the questions database with the word "noodles", everything is working the the database connection and my node server

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What your query is doing is finding documents where the `text` property matches `"noodles"` exactly.  Assuming you're trying to query for documents where the `text` property simply *contains* `"noodles"` somewhere, you should use a regular expression instead:

```
app.get('/search', function(req,res){
    var regex = new RegExp('noodles', 'i');  // 'i' makes it case insensitive
    return Questions.find({text: regex}, function(err,q){
        return res.send(q);
    });
});
```

Comment: how can i send `regex` as a parameter for the api, for example `/search/regex`

Comment: thanks i solved it i just have to send regex as a param like so `/search/:key`, and then in the body just have `var regex = new RegExp(req.params.key,'i');` :)

Comment: You could also use queries like so. ```/search/?q=key``` and then ```var regex = new RegExp(req.query.q);```

Comment: thx for the solution. though it seems that 'i' doesn't make it case sensitive

Comment: @mdehghani Hmm...the docs for `RegExp` showing the `i` option are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax). Maybe post a new question if it's still not working for you.